# joomla 3 stored mysql procedure output how to format

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

It maybe something simple, but I keep trying and can't get it done.  I'm using Joomla 3 with a mysql backend that has a custom made procedure (blogvote(i int)) which returns votes and assigns points based on vote - basically it is a simple code like this:

```
    SELECT FLOOR(COUNT(`vote`)/10) AS POINTS, COUNT(`vote`) AS LIKES FROM `table1`, `table2` b
WHERE b.`id` = `item_id` AND b.`user_id` = p_user
AND `vote` = 1
GROUP BY b.`user_id`;
```

Then I use a custom made module with php code like this:

```
require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_helloworld');
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $user =& JFactory::getUser();
//display user name and user id
    echo "<p>Your name is {$user->name} and your userid is {$user->id}</p>";
//get logged in user id to put into procedure call
    $userval = $user->id;
    //create query call to procedure
    $query = "CALL blogvote($userval);";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    // $result = $db->query();
    //print_r($result);
    $row = $db->loadObjectList('user_id');
    print_r($row);
require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_helloworld');
```

It works now - i.e. I get the likes and points for a logged in user.  I'd like to format it as a table - more or less like I have the output on phpmyadmin

Likes  Points

---

3                0

And now I get something like this:

```
Array ( [] => stdClass Object ( [POINTS] => 0 [LIKES] => 3 ) )
```

How can I get a proper formatting if possible from php module file?

Comment: Try asking your question over at [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) ;)

Comment: I'll do that, thank you for advice.  But I thought someone at stackoverflow may know as well.

Comment: So you get an array of results, make some html, where you start the table,  and then loop through the array generating the html for the rows, and then close up the table.